# Rails has_many clear method

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, has-many

According to the [documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has_many-association-reference) Rails `has_many` association has `clear` method. Looks like it executes sql `delete` query immediately after it performs. Is there a canonical way to delete all the child objects and update association only at the moment of `save` method? For example:

```
@cart.container_items.delete_all_example # looks like `clear` execute sql at this line
if @cart.save
  # do smth
else
  #do smth
end
```

it is necessary because of many changes at the parent object and they must be committed all or none of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Cart.transaction do
  @cart.container_items.delete_all_example # looks like `clear` execute sql at this line
  if @cart.save
    # success
  else
    # error
    raise ActiveRecord::Rollback
  end
end
```

`ActiveRecord::Rollback` is not propagated outside the transaction block. It simply terminates the transaction.

Answer (score 4):

You don't want to `delete_all`, you want to `destroy_all`.

Calling `delete_all` executes a simple SQL `delete`, ignoring any callbacks and dependent records.

Using `destroy_all` invokes the `destroy` method on each object, allowing `:dependent => :destroy` to work as expected, cleaning up child records.

This does *not* destroy all objects at the point of `save`, and there is no canonical way to do that as you're not *saving* the record. Rails persists destroys at the point of the method call, not at a later `save`. If you need many destroys to be transactional, wrap them in a transaction:

```
Cart.begin do
  @cart.container_items.delete_all_example
end
```

Comment: It executes sql at the 'destroy_all' line. I want to do it at the save method.

Comment: That's not how Rails destroys objects. The destroy is persisted as the point the method is called, not at a later `save`. There is no easy way (or real reason) to do what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like i'm trying to do a `transaction`. Some articles to learn more about it:

- [Transations in Rails](http://markdaggett.com/blog/2011/12/01/transactions-in-rails/)
- [Active record transactions](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html)